# Android webview app won't load my form

Tags: java, android, webview

Hi i've been searching a lot but couldn't find anything that could help.

I am creating an android app for our existing website. The website itself will load, but the main form where users can sign in won't load. Does anyone have any idea how this happens?
The website is https://app.one-2-ten.com/v2

p.s. This is the first time I am making an android app so sorry if its an obvious solution.

```
ProgressBar progressBar;


WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    else{
        webView.getSettings() .setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings() .setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings() .setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings() .setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings() .setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());
        webView.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged (WebView view, int progress){
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }if(progress == 100){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }

                }
            }
        );}

        String data = getIntent() .getDataString();

        if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(getIntent() .getAction())){
            webView.loadUrl(data);
        }else{
            webView.loadUrl("https://one2ten-system.parseapp.com/v2");
        }

    }

public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
        if (url.contains("one2ten-system.parseapp.com/v2")) {
            v.loadUrl(url);
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        } else {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri), "Choose browser"));
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}
```

}

Comment: Going to need at least some Android code, How are you loading the form into the `WebView`

Comment: have you set the webviewclient/webchromeclient? have you enabled JS in webView?

Comment: Sorry, i've added my mainActivity file, but i have enabled js

Comment: @VladMatvienko Sorry I forgot to mention you guy's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found what my issue was, I forgot to add the following line: webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

This enables the browser to store user data from forms for example, which it needs because you land on a login page.

If my answer is incomplete please let me know!
Thanks